# C# Get combinations for every 6 months period from list

Tags: c#, list

I have sales only in following months, and like to create report for every 6 months, I'm trying to figure out how to get combinations for every 6 months period.

```
List<MyDate> list = new List<MyDate>();

list.Add(new MyDate(){ Year=2014, Month=4});
list.Add(new MyDate(){ Year=2014, Month=6});
list.Add(new MyDate(){ Year=2014, Month=8});
list.Add(new MyDate(){ Year=2015, Month=1});
list.Add(new MyDate(){ Year=2015, Month=3});
list.Add(new MyDate(){ Year=2016, Month=1});    

List<List<MyDate>> output = Get6MonthsCombinations(); // This is method I like to create
```

I like the output look like following

```
// output[0] -> {Year=2014,Month=4},{Year=2014,Month=6},{Year=2014, Month=8}
// output[1] -> {Year=2014,Month=8},{Year=2015,Month=1}
// output[2] -> {Year=2015,Month=1},{Year=2015,Month=3}
// output[3] -> {Year=2016,Month=1}
```

Comment: what are the rules here? The output doesn't make much sense if you don't give the rules.

Comment: I'm still stuck trying to figure out what you are trying to figure out... lol

Comment: I thought I understood the question, but looking at the output, it doesn't make sense. What's a 6-month combination?

Comment: @Dennis_E Imagine you start at some month, you find everything in the list that falls within 6 months of that date.  Then advance a month and do the same thing.  I think the question is to find all non empty sets of that.  At least that's the brute force way of doing it.  There's probably a better way to do it though.

Comment: Instead of making your own MyDate class, use the existing DateTime class.. it will be infinitely easier to deal with.

Comment: Just what i thought this instance =P

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you treat 183 days as half a year:

```
List<List<MyDate>> Get6MonthsCombinations(List<MyDate> input)
{
    List<List<MyDate>> output = new List<List<MyDate>>();
    var ordered = input.OrderBy(x => x.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Month).ToList();
    if(ordered.Count == 0)
        return output;
    DateTime periodStart = new DateTime(ordered[0].Year,ordered[0].Month, 1);
    output.Add(new List<MyDate>());
    foreach (MyDate md in ordered)
    { 
        DateTime month = new DateTime(md.Year, md.Month,1 );
        if ((month - periodStart).Days > 183)
        {
            output.Add(new List<MyDate>());
            periodStart = month;
        }
        output.Last().Add(md);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, results missing {Year=2014,Month=8},{Year=2015,Month=1}, I will like to get all possible combinations. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielZ: i don't understand your rules. I now have understood that you want all possible combinations of objects that are in the same half-year. But then your desired result seems to be incorrect. For example, the first list contains three objects, that's correct. But why does the second list start with `Year=2014,Month=8` and not with `Year=2014,Month=6`? That object has also a possible combination with `Year=2014,Month=8`. So your result omits the possible list `{ Year=2014,Month=6, Year=2014,Month=8 }`. Because they were in the first list? But you add them also to multiple lists.

Comment: Because they were in the first list? Yes, if I have list contains {1,2,3}, I don't want to {1,3}

Comment: @DanielZ: yes, but you "repeat" every object anyway, for example `Year=2014,Month=8` is in the first and the second list. So what are the rules, what are "possible combinations"?

Comment: if I have list contains {1,2,3}, I don't want to {1,3},but I still want {1,4}. In my case, I want if the time period overlaps, but I don't want one time period contains other one. Sorry for all the confuse.

Answer (score 0):

I first try to explain, what you mean (I think).

You want to slide a 6 month window over the monthlist and get any combination of month that fit in a 6 month range? Right?

Then either your output should start with {Year=2014,Month=4} or should not end with {Year=2016,Month=1}.

To achieve this, use two indexes (start and end). Both set to 0 at start. Increment the second (end of window) and check if month[start] to month[end] exceeds the 6 month. If yes, increment the start, starting a new result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is ordered:

```
var output = new List<List<MyDate>>();

int first = 0;
while (first < list.Count) {
    var values = new List<MyDate>();
    values.Add(list[first]);
    int next = first+1;
    for ( ; next < list.Count; ++next) {
        if (list[next].Year * 12 + list[next].Month
            - (list[first].Year * 12 + list[first].Month) < 6) {
            values.Add(list[next]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    output.Add(values);
    first = next;
}
```